# How many steps does this subtractive recurrence take?

Tags: nt.number-theory, asymptotics, recurrences

Given $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $c\geq1$.

$n$ here is in naturals $\mathbb N$.

$$T_0=n$$
$$T_i=T_{i-1}-\frac{\lfloor{T_{i-1}}^\alpha\rfloor}c\mbox{ at every }i\in\mathbb N$$
is the recursion.

> At what $i$ does this recursion take to reach $<2$? Is it $\leq\frac{(1-\alpha) c}{\alpha}n^{1-\alpha}$ or something bigger?

Comment: The answer is indeed of the form $O(n^{1-\alpha}polylog(n))$

Comment: Since your sequence clearly decrease with a sub-linear speed, you can w.l.o.g. consider the inverse problem: set $F_0$ as $1$ (or $2$, it doesn't matter) and for all positive $i$, set $F_i = F_{i-1}+F_{i-1}^{\alpha}$. Check that $f_i = i^\beta/c$ gives the lower bound on $F_i$ for $\beta = 1/(1-\alpha)$ for some large $c=c(\alpha)$, since $(f(i)-f(i-1))/f(i-1)^\alpha$ is less than 1 for all i. Therefore, $F_i$ surpasses $n$ even faster than $f_i$, while the latter does that on the $O(n^{1/\beta})$'th step, where the hidden constant here may depend on $\alpha$

Comment: I'm sorry that my answer is rather implicit. But the missing details look like a standart and tedious work. Hope it was still helpful